# R and Exponential, standard 2nd Order

Tags: r, curve-fitting, exponential

Here is part of my dataset, a classical 2 columns dataset with Time in Col1 and Current in Col2

```
Time = c(10950 11000 11050 11100 11150 11200 11250 11300 11350 11400 11450 11500 11550 11600 11650 11700 11750 11800 11850 11900 11950 12000 12050 12100 12150 12200 12250 12300 12350 12400 12450 12500 12550 12600 12650 12700 12750 12800 12850 12900 12950 13000 13050 13100 13150 13200 13250 13300 13350 13400 13450 13500 13550 13600 13650 13700 13750 13800 13850 13900 13950 14000 14050 14100 14150 14200 14250 14300 14350 14400 14450 14500 14550 14600 14650 14700 14750 14800 14850 14900 14950 15000)
Current = c(-2616.000 -2406.000 -2190.000 -1983.000 -1797.000 -1630.000 -1484.000 -1356.000 -1243.000 -1143.000 -1058.000  -983.093  -914.650  -852.429 -797.985  -751.320  -713.987  -681.321  -650.210  -622.211  -598.878  -577.101  -552.212  -527.324  -503.991  -485.324  -469.769  -455.769 -441.770  -429.325  -416.881  -407.548  -398.215  -391.993  -382.660  -371.771  -362.438  -349.994  -335.994  -325.105  -320.439  -320.439 -317.328  -311.105  -304.883  -297.106  -289.328  -283.106  -279.995  -273.773  -267.551  -261.329  -259.773  -258.218  -256.662  -256.662 -253.551  -250.440  -248.884  -245.773  -242.662  -241.107  -242.662  -237.996  -228.662  -220.885  -216.218  -209.996  -203.774  -202.219 -203.774  -200.663  -195.996  -192.885  -189.774  -188.219  -186.663  -181.997)

df = cbind(Time,Current)
```

This dataset should be fitted by:

```
Current ~ A1*exp(-Time/Tau1) + A2*exp(-Time/Tau2) + c
```

I used this code:

```
nls(Current ~ A1*exp(-Time/Tau1) + A2*exp(-Time/Tau2) + c,
+             start=list(Tau1=2, A1 = -500, Tau2=0.3, A2 = -1999, c= 84),
+             data = inactivation, control = nls.control(maxiter = 1000000, minFactor = 1e-10))
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  matrice de gradient singulière pour les estimations initiales des paramètres
```

When i'm fiting with Clampfit (commercial software) with the same equation it works well and I obtained these parameters:

```
A1 = -576.224914550781250   
Tau1 = 2.239131927490234    
A2 = -1999.030639648437500  
Tau2 = 0.372585743665695    
c = 84.324699401855469
```

Do somebody tried and succed this already?

Comment: I get a different number of values for Time and Current in the data you posted. Would you please verify?

Comment: I found the answer: nls is fitting from 0 to the end of the daatset. My dataset starts at 10950. So nls () tries to extrapolate a lot in order to fit. I shiffted all to 0 and it works. Do you know if it's possible to change starting point? Not 0 but 5 for example?

Comment: I do not use R. This sounds like an excellent separate, second question if you would please post it that way.